# Disable URL ( deep linking) in ionic 3

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm working on an ionic 3 project where we are required to disable url(deep linking. But I don't know how to do it. It would be great if anyone can help me out in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do Lazy loading if you want to disable URL in Ionic 3. You will then need to load all components at the start of the application and declaring them in 'declarations' and 'entry components' in app.module.ts.
But remember it will lead to slow startup time for your application.